# Pass state from App.js to React Router component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, state

I have a state in `App.js` that gets populated with animal data returned by an API. This data is accessible with `this.state.animals` on the component that is loaded, but my problem is when changing routes to `/animals`, I can no longer call `this.state.animals`. It's as if I no longer have access or the data is gone. How can I pass the state to any component when I navigate to them?

**App.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, NavLink } from 'react-router-dom'
import Animals from './components/Animals'

class App extends Component {
  state = {
    animals: []
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch('animals api path here')
    .then(result => result.json())
    .then((data) => {
      this.setState({ animals: data })
    })
    .catch(console.log)
  }

  render() {
    return (
          <Router>
            <NavLink to="/animals">animals</NavLink>
            <Route exact path="/animals" render={()=> <Animals parentState={this.state.animals} />} />
          </Router>
    );
  }
}

export default App
```

**components/Animals.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

class Animals extends Component {
  render() {
    console.log(this.state.animals)
    return (
      <h2>Animals</h2>
    //<div>I would loop through and list the animals if I could...</div>
    )
  }
}

export default Animals
```

Comment: did you try accessing it in Animals as `this.props.parentState`?

Comment: I think you need to employ Redux or Flux if you want to persist data when navigating from one route to the next.

Comment: @NicholasTower you might be on to something... will report back

Comment: @NicholasTower this was indeed the case. Thanks for pointing this out, works great!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this example if you want to access animal data, it would be `{this.props.parentState}` inside fo the animal component

Answer (score 0):

Your `Route` declaration is defined outside the context of the router. When using React-Router, all your  components should have among their ancestors a . Usually,  is the top-level component rendered in  (at least if you are not using other libraries that need root-context definition, like Redux).

Comment: This was an issue with pasting my code in, updated my code above.

Comment: Than, as pointed out by Nicholas Tower, just access it as this.props.parentState in your animals component